# Ember statemanager vs sproutcore-statechart in emberjs add-ons

Tags: ember.js, statechart

There are some examples that showcase the use of statechart in an Ember based application :

http://www.thesoftwaresimpleton.com/blog/2012/02/28/statemachine/

https://github.com/DominikGuzei/ember-routing-statechart-example

What is the difference between sproutcore-statechart in emberjs-addons and the ember.statemanager in ember-states lib ?
And if I'd like to use sproutcore-statechart with Emberjs, how can I set it up correctly ?

Comment: I've just visited the emberjs website and find there some new about this. I think, what I need is just Ember.StateManager as described here :

http://docs.emberjs.com/symbols/Ember.StateManager.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some great new docs in code comment (by trek) on StateManager were merged just two days ago:

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-states/lib/state_manager.js

Enjoy!

Answer (score 5):

Ember has a new States system written from scratch. However, some users from the SC2 days were relying on SproutCore's Statecharts, so the "sproutcore-statechart" system brings that in. It's pretty much just for legacy use. I recommend that new users just use the built-in Ember States.